# Could this part of the sentence 'If on that day, everything were as usual' be inverted as 'On that day, were everything as usual' and so on?

Tags: subjunctives, inversion, if

I'm making present sentences I like to practice my subjunctive mood.

Several of the continuous sentences like that:

> If on that day, everything were as usual...
> If only he never came into
> my life... So maybe, the cruel truth would remain hidden.

I inverted the first sentence as:

> On that day, were everything as usual...

or

> Were everything as usual on that day...

Do you think they are both correct? Additionally, could *had been* be used to replace *were* in this sentence?